# Ideals of the ring of power set

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $S$ be an infinite set and consider the ring, $\langle P(S), \triangle, \cap \rangle$.

1. Show that the collection, $J$, of finite subsets of $S$ is an ideal of $P(S)$.
2. Let $I$ be an ideal of $P(S)$. Show that $I$ is a prime ideal if and only if the following holds: $\forall A \in P(S)$ or $A \subseteq S$, either $A \in I$ or $A^\complement= S \setminus A \in I$ but not both.

Answer (score 2):

It is so much easier to think about that in terms of $P(S) \cong \operatorname{Maps}(S,\mathbb F_2) :=R$ with the identification $$P(S) \ni A \longleftrightarrow \chi_A \in \operatorname{Maps}(S,\mathbb F_2)$$

The first statement then says: Take a map, which vanishes almost anywhere. If you multiply it with any map, it still vanishes almost anywhere.

The second statement says: $I$ is prime iff if either $f$ or $1-f$ is contained in $I$ for any $f \in R$.

Let $I$ be prime. Note That $f(1-f)=0$ and $f+(1-f)=1$. The first shows that one of them is contained in $I$, the latter shows that not both of them can be contained in $I$.

Now let the condition hold: $f \in I$ or $1-f \in I$ tells us, that $f=0$ or $f=1$ in $R/I$. This holds for any $f$, hence $R/I \cong \mathbb F_2$, which shows that $I$ is prime (even maximal).

Comment: Thanks, MooS, but I'm only starting a course on abstract algebra. I currenlty still do not understand what you mean by $P(S) \cong \operatorname{Maps}(S,\mathbb F_2) :=R$. Can you make it easier to understand, using standard set theoretic concepts? Again, thanks for the immediate answer

Comment: My idea for (1) is, since $J$ is a set of finite subsets of $S$, then $J \in P(S)$. Then, if $A \in J$ and $B \in P(S)$ we show that $A \cap B \in J$. If we let $a \in A \cap B$, then $a \in A$ and $a \in B$. But $A \in J$ and $B \in P(S)$, so $a \in J \cap P(S)$. But $J \cap P(S) = J$, so $A \cap B \in J$.

Comment: Yes, thats hardly a idea, but more a correct tracking of the definition of an ideal. You precisely have to do this. Moreover  you have to show that the symmetric difference of two finite sets is again finite.

Comment: For the second one, my idea for the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction is: Let $I$ be a prime ideal. Let $P(A), P(B) \unlhd P(S)$ such that $P(A) \cap P(B) \subseteq I$. Thus, $P(A) \subseteq I$ and $P(B) \subseteq I$. If $P(A) \subseteq I$, then $A \in P(A)$ and consequently, $A \in I$. I can't show why $A^\complement \not\in I$.

Answer (score 0):

The checks for $J$ to be an ideal are

- $\emptyset$ is finite
- The symmetric difference of two finite subsets is finite
- The intersection of a finite subset with any subset is finite

If $I$ is a prime ideal of $P(S)$, then $P(S)/I$ is a boolean ring and an integral domain. It follows that $P(S)/I$ is the two element boolean ring, because $x(1-x)=0$ holds for any element $x$ in a boolean ring.

Thus for an element $A\in P(S)$ either $A\in I$ or $A\notin I$.

Conversely, if the condition holds, $P(S)/I$ has two elements, so it is a field and $I$ is a prime ideal.